# Generic OOP Implementation of a Deck-package in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, generics, playing-cards

I have posted some versions of this question (or at least similar ones) before. But I once again tried to improve it.

The goal is to be able to use this package whether it's for a traditional card-game or a completely different type of cards.

I'd like input on best practices with regards to OOP and the overall structure.

Here all the interfaces:

**Card.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;


public interface Card<T>  {
    boolean isConsecutive(T other);
    boolean isEquals(T other);
}
```

**Deck.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.Comparator;


public interface Deck<T extends Card> {
    void shuffle();
    void sort(Comparator<T> sort);
    <S extends Receivable<T>> void addCardToPlayers(S... players);
}
```

**Hand.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.List;


public interface Hand<T extends Card> {
   int calculate();
   void addCardToDeck(int index, List<? super Card> deck);
   boolean isEquals(Hand<T> other);
}
```

**Receivable.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.List;


public interface Receivable<T extends Card> {
    void addCards(List<T> cards);
    void addCard(T card);
    void addCard(int index, T card);
}
```

**Sendable.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.List;


public interface Sendable<T extends Card> {
    List<T> removeCards(int numberOfCards);
    List<T> removeCards(int... indices);
    T removeCard();
    T removeCard(int index);
}
```

**Playable.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;


public interface Playable<T extends Card> extends Sendable<T>, Receivable<T> {
}
```

The next class is Abstract, without any abstract methods. But I did not want it instantiable, while still being able to inherit from it.

**AbstractOperation.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


public abstract class AbstractCardOperation<T extends Card> implements Receivable<T>, Sendable<T>  {
    protected List<T> cards;

    public AbstractCardOperation() {
        this.cards = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public AbstractCardOperation(List<T> cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    public AbstractCardOperation(List<T> list, int size) {
        this.cards = IntStream.range(0, size)
                .mapToObj(i -> list)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> removeCards(int numberOfCards) {
        return IntStream.range(0, numberOfCards)
                .mapToObj(i -> cards.remove(i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> removeCards(int... indices) {
        List<T> removedCards = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.stream(indices).forEach(index -> removedCards.add(cards.remove(index)));
        return removedCards;
    }

    @Override
    public T removeCard() {
        if (cards.size() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Deck is empty");
        }
        return cards.remove(0);
    }

    @Override
    public T removeCard(int index) {
        if (cards.size() - 1 < index) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return cards.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCards(List<T> cards) {
        this.cards.addAll(cards);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCard(T card) {
        cards.add(card);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCard(int index, T card) {
        cards.add(index, card);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return cards.toString();
    }

    public List<T> getCards() {
        return cards;
    }
}
```

**BaseDeck.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;


public class BaseDeck<T extends Card> extends AbstractCardOperation<T> implements Deck<T> {

    public BaseDeck() {
        super();
    }

    public BaseDeck(List<T> deck) {
        super(deck);
    }

    public BaseDeck(List<T> deck, int numberOfDecks) {
        super(deck, numberOfDecks);
    }

    @Override
    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(super.cards);
    }

    @Override
    public void sort(Comparator<T> sort) {
        super.cards.sort(sort);
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Receivable<T>> void addCardToPlayers(S[] players) {
        Arrays.asList(players).forEach(player -> player.addCard(super.cards.remove(0)));
    }


    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T extends Card> void print(Deck<T>... decks) {
        Arrays.stream(decks).forEach(deck -> System.out.println(deck.toString()));
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return super.cards.size();
    }
}
```

**BaseHand.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.List;


public class BaseHand<T extends Card> extends AbstractCardOperation<T> implements Hand<T> {

    public BaseHand(List<T> cards) {
        super(cards);
    }

    @Override
    public int calculate() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCardToDeck(int index, List<? super Card> deck) {
        deck.add(super.cards.remove(index));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEquals(Hand<T> other) {
        return super.cards.equals(other);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     public void addCardToDeck(int index, List<? super Card> deck) {
>         deck.add(super.cards.remove(index));
>     }
> ```

If this is how the method is supposed to work, consider changing the name from `add` to `move`.

```
    public void moveCardToDeck(int index, List<? super Card> deck) {
        deck.add(super.cards.remove(index));
    }
```

This way it is clearer that the method removes the card from the hand as well as adding it to the deck.

You also may want to add some Javadoc to comment this behavior so that people who implement the method understand that this should do both things.

There is a school of thought that people shouldn't use extension in Java, only interfaces.  The problem with abstract classes is that they confuse the location of implementation.  E.g. a method could be defined in `DerivedHand`, `BaseHand`, and `AbstractCardOperation`.  As the number of extensions and implementations increase, this only gets worse.  Another problem is that you can only chain extensions.  There's no multiple inheritance of abstract classes.

Anyway, I don't want to pick sides in that particular holy war today.  I just didn't want to start using an abstract class before noting that there are arguments against it.  In this case, you already have an abstract class, so there isn't much point in not using it for things unless we're going to get rid of it.

The name `AbstractCardOperation` is not quite correct.  It doesn't represent a single operation but a number of methods.  If it weren't abstract, you might call it `CardOperations` or `CardUtilities`.  As is, maybe `AbstractCardCollection` would be better.  That would fit with extensions by `BaseHand` and `BaseDeck`.

Why is `deck` a `List` of `Card` objects?  Why not an `AbstractCardCollection`?  To pass a `List` to the method, you'll have to excavate the `cards` from your `AbstractCardCollection` (as your `BaseDeck` type `extends AbstractCardCollection`).  And what if you are playing a game where cards get passed from player to player?  And why isn't the move operation on `AbstractCardCollection` rather than `Hand`?

Be careful you don't make too many base classes and interfaces.  For example, when do you use `Sendable` separate from `Receivable` and `AbstractCardOperation`?

It might be useful to implement a remove-only `Hand` or `Deck`, but it would be difficult to do here.  They couldn't extend `BaseHand` and `BaseDeck` or `AbstractCardCollection`, because all of those have the `Receivable` operations.

> ```
>     public boolean isEquals(Hand<T> other) {
>         return super.cards.equals(other);
>     }
> ```

Does this even compile?  The `cards` object is a `List`, while `other` is a `Hand`.  If it does compile, it is almost certainly going to `return false` because it is going to go back to `Object.equals`.  It would only `return true` if the `List` and the `Hand` were the same object.

Equality doesn't seem like a natural operation for `Hand`.  Yes, there may be times when it is useful, but for many games, it is meaningless.  For example, Go Fish.  You have a hand, but you would never compare it to another player's hand.  The operation there is to check if you have a card of a particular rank.  In Blackjack, it's less if two hands are equal and more if one is better than the other.  If the player's hand is better than the dealer's, then the player wins.  Otherwise the dealer does.

Comment: Thank you very much. Lots of good points indeed. The thing you wrote here: `Why is deck a List of Card objects? Why not an AbstractCardCollection?`. I didn't quit get that. Would you care to elaborate a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

- Your type `Card<T>` is generic. You have a *Card of T*. When I hear that, it doesn't make sense to me. A card is a card. Why do you need the `T` here? Could you have a *Card of Wine*, a *Card of Deck*?
- A card in itself cannot be consecutive. Standard playing cards have a *rank* and a *suit*, but which ranks are consecutive depends on the game. In Skat, the 10 is ranked between A and K, while in other games it is ranked between J and 9.
- In the type `Deck`, you use the type `Card`, but without specifying the *type* of card, i.e. you left out the `T` in `Card<T>`.
- The method `Deck.addCardToPlayers` should rather be called `deal`. It should only deal a single card to a single player.
- In `Deck.addCardToPlayers`, why is the receiving type called `S` instead of `R` (receiver) or `P` (player)?
- Not every `Hand` can be evaluated to a simple `int`. In Poker, you can do some bit fiddling to map all possible hands into a 32-bit number so that different hands can be compared easily. This is not possible for all games.
- A general note: Before creating so many abstract classes and interfaces, you should implement 3 different games using the most concrete types possible. I would start with these types:

  - `enum Suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES }`
  - `enum Rank { ACE, TWO, THREE, ... }`
  - `class Card { Suit suit; Rank rank; }`
  - `class Hand { List<Card> cards; }`
  - `class Deck { List<Card> cards; }`

  See how far you get with these simple definitions. If you need more, add them. Learn about the YAGNI principle.

  When you have implemented 3 different games, have a look back and see which abstractions you really need. Only make these abstract.

Comment: valid points all around. But i want this package to be applicable with not just regular playing-cards. It could just as easily be pokemon-cards. So suits and ranks will not always be the case.

Comment: Unless you have any direct and obvious benefit of merging several card types into one Java class, you should avoid it. Pokémon cards have practically nothing in common with Poker cards, so there is no reason to force them into the same Java class.